# unable to build the webpack with react file

Tags: webpack

> webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js

error: unknown option '--config'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options

````
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack  --config webpack.prod.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...otherdependency,
    "webpack-cli": "4.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "5.4.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6"
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have webpack installed in your devDependencies. I see webpack-cli, I see webpack-dev-server. I do not see, for example:

```
"webpack": "^5.18.0",
```

Is this just a cross-section? Or is this your full package.json?

A simple:

```
npm i -D webpack
```

might be all you need.